# Calendar Get Next Month

Tags: java, calendar

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.OCTOBER);
c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 31);
c.set(Calendar.MONTH, c.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1); //Returns Dec 1. Expect Nov 30.
```

If I have a calendar object and the last day of a month falls on the 31st and the next month has less days than the previous, how can I ensure that by setting the month ahead I will not go beyond the next month?

Comment: Probably better to use add() instead of set()

Comment: Add returns the same results. I understand the calendar is reacting normally, but in my specific case i'd like the date to not span beyond the actual next month, even if it means returns a different day of the month.

Comment: @ryandlf means u want next month last date ?

Comment: `c.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);`  I get Nov 30

Comment: You're right. I tried again and it worked as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `add()` instead of `set()` as the Calendar is "smart" enough to determine the difference of days and such...

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.OCTOBER);
    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 31);
    c.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
    System.out.println(c.getTime());
}
```

Output (as of my current run):

```
Sun Nov 30 09:08:01 EST 2014
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Calendar JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html):

> **Leniency**
>
> Calendar has two modes for interpreting the calendar fields, lenient
>   and non-lenient. When a Calendar is in lenient mode, it accepts a
>   wider range of calendar field values than it produces. When a Calendar
>   recomputes calendar field values for return by get(), all of the
>   calendar fields are normalized. For example, a lenient
>   GregorianCalendar interprets MONTH == JANUARY, DAY_OF_MONTH == 32 as
>   February 1.

This means that when you add 1 to the MONTH, the value of DAY_OF_MONTH is still 31. But November doesn't have a 31st day. This means that if the Calendar you are using is lenient, it will interpret MONTH == 11, DAY_OF_MONTH == 31 as December 1.